# d3.js v5 - Reading a Element from SVG

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg, rect

I am a novice in [**D3.Js**](https://d3js.org/). I am using **[v5](https://github.com/d3/d3/releases/tag/v5.2.0)** of D3js.

What I am trying to do is store a **rect** element inside a **svg** variable like this-

```
var rectangleElement = d3.select('svg').append('rect').attr('class', 'rectangle').call(dragR);
```

then want to retrieve the **rect** element like this-

```
var rect = d3.select(self.rectangleElement[0][0]);
```

But I am getting this error-

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

[image: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined]

At that time, if I log **rectangleElement** in the console, then I am finding this-

[image]

I am trying this code from d3 v3, in there it was working.

But in d3 v5, I am getting this error.

Can anyone please help me solving this error?

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: What is `self`? How did you define it?

Comment: Seems like it moved to `rectangleElement._groups[0][0]` A much better way would be `rectangleElement.node()`

Comment: @Abrar Selections are objects since D3 v4.

Comment: Just assign an id to the rect and select by using d3.select('#rectID')